# Difficulty with error bars on facet_wrap() object

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I'm attempting to add error bars to a facet_wrap plot, but can't seem to get R to produce the plot that I want without error messages. I wrote the following code, which produces the plot which I want, however I can't seem to get the errorbar portion of the code to work properly.

```
ggplot(data = filter(Total, Cell_Line != "stDev"), aes(Time, Killing)) + 
  geom_line(data = transform(filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type"), Cell_Line = NULL), group = 1) +
  #geom_errorbar(aes(x = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,2], ymax = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,3] + filter(Total, Cell_Line == "stDev")[,3], ymin = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type")[,3] - filter(Total, Cell_Line == "stDev")[,3]), data = filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type" | Cell_Line == "stDev")) +
  geom_point(colour = "cadetblue") +
  facet_grid_paginate(Cell_Line ~ Run, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
```

This code produces the plot [Sample Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTBZC.png), which is almost what I want, it's just missing error bars on the black line.

Here's the top of the dataframe I'm using to produce the plot:

```
Total <-
structure(list(Cell_Line = c("3", "7", "8", "17", "19", "20", 
"29", "33", "38", "47", "49", "53", "55", "Wild_Type", "stDev", 
"3", "7", "8", "17", "19", "20", "29", "33", "38", "47", "49", 
"53", "55", "Wild_Type", "stDev"), Time = c("00", "00", "00", 
"00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
"00", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02"), Killing = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0704388, 0.2881066, -0.0132908, 
0.04700991, 0.03049371, -0.02243472, 0.1513817, 0.129636, 0.09328508, 
0.05876777, 0.1063291, 0.0357473, 0.1974026, 0.07732854, 0.07383331
), Run = c("run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", 
"run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", 
"run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", 
"run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1", "run1")), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the current error message I'm getting:_

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (90): x, ymax, ymin

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this by reshaping the data for the error bars so that they will have access to the values they need within different columns of each row.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggforce)
ggplot(data = filter(Total, Cell_Line != "stDev"), aes(Time, Killing)) + 
  geom_line(data = transform(filter(Total, Cell_Line == "Wild_Type"), Cell_Line = NULL), group = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(data = Total %>% filter(Cell_Line %in% c("Wild_Type", "stDev")) %>% 
                  spread(Cell_Line, Killing),
                aes(x = Time, y = Wild_Type, ymax = Wild_Type + stDev, ymin = Wild_Type - stDev)) +      
  geom_point(colour = "cadetblue") +
  facet_grid_paginate(Cell_Line ~ Run, ncol = 4, nrow = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!